# how do i create a non access page until user signup

Tags: php, session, post, header

i want a create a congrats page ('congrats page')where users should be redirected to after submitting the form , even if they know the link to the 'congrats page' and they try accessing it without signning it should take them to a signup page

```js
//signup.php (signup page)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width
        ,initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="../css/signup.css">  
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="container"> <!---------------------------- red------------------------------------------->
  <div class="headerdiv">
   <div class="imagediv">
   </div>
  </div> 
  <div id ="main">
  <form action="../include/signup.inc.php" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="firstname">
   <br>
   <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="lastname">
   <br>
   <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="username">
   <br>
   <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email">
   <br>
   <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="password">
   <br>
   <button type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
  </form>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 include_once 'connect.php';
 
 
 $fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['fname']);
 $lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['lname']);
 $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
 $uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uname']);
 $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']); 
  
  if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    header("Location: ../php/signup.php?signup=email");
    exit();
   } else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uname='$uname'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    
    if($resultCheck > 0) {
     header("Location: ../php/signup.php?signup=usertaken");
              exit(); 
     
    } else {
     // hashing the password
     $hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
     //Insert the user into the database
     $sql = "INSERT INTO user (fname, lname, email, uname, pwd) VALUES ('$fname',
     '$lname', '$email', '$uname', '$hashedPwd');";
     mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
     header("Location: ../php/congrats.php");
              exit(); 
    }
   }
  }
 }
 
} else {
 header("Location: ../php/signup.php");
 exit();
}



//////////////////////////////


/// the congrats page ('congrats.php')


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width
        ,initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="../css/congrats.css">  
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <p>REGISTRATION SUCCESS</p>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php


//connection to data base


$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$database = 'webz';

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
```

i want a create a congrats page ('congrats page')where users should be redirected to after submitting the form , even if they know the link to the 'congrats page' and they try accessing it without signning it should take them to a signup page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try PHP $_SESSION, which is an associative array contains all the session variables available to the current script. Set the session variable whenever user successfully logged into the application and check it where you want to restrict the user to access the page without login.

```
 <?php

    session_start();

    // to set the session variable // for e.g; user_id
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = ''; // valid user_id.

    // check the session variable // for congrats page

    if(!empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    // congrats page
    }else{
      header('Location: http://www.example.com/signup');
    }

    // session_destroy(); // use when user logs out.
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use $_SESSION to do the job.
After the user signs up, you store something to the $_SESSION variable.

e.g.

```
session_start();
//after sign up
$_SESSION['signedup']=1;
```

And at the congrats page, check the variable

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['signedup']){
   //show the page
}else{
   header('Location: http://www.example.com/signup');
}
```